# call function of key press

Tags: c#, function, combobox

i'm using the following code to autocomplete entry data in combobox

```
private void AutoCompleteCombo(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
  { 
      ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
                cb.DroppedDown = true;
                string strFindStr = "";
                if (e.KeyChar == (char)8)
                {
                    if (cb.SelectionStart <= 1)
                    {
                        cb.Text = "";
                        return;
                    }

                    if (cb.SelectionLength == 0)
                        strFindStr = cb.Text.Substring(0, cb.Text.Length - 1);
                    else
                        strFindStr = cb.Text.Substring(0, cb.SelectionStart - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (cb.SelectionLength == 0)
                        strFindStr = cb.Text + e.KeyChar;
                    else
                        strFindStr = cb.Text.Substring(0, cb.SelectionStart) + e.KeyChar;
                }
                int intIdx = -1;
                // Search the string in the ComboBox list.
                intIdx = cb.FindString(strFindStr);
                if (intIdx != -1)
                {
                    cb.SelectedText = "";
                    cb.SelectedIndex = intIdx;
                    cb.SelectionStart = strFindStr.Length;
                    cb.SelectionLength = cb.Text.Length;
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
                else
                    e.Handled = true;
}
```

it works fine .... but i'm trying to call it in my combobox event keypress

```
private void cmbState_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteCombo();
}
```

but it gives me an error

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'sender' of 'FRM_AddClient.AutoCompleteCombo(object,
>   KeyPressEventArgs)'

sorry ... i'm new at programming

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, your method receives two parameters wich should be of type "object" and "KeyPressEventArgs". 
`private void AutoCompleteCombo(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)` 
So when you try to execute your method, you have to pass by parameters this type of objects in the same way they are expected.

Try with this:

```
AutoCompleteCombo(sender, e);
```

Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the arguments from the handler to the AutoCompleteCombo method:

```
private void cmbState_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteCombo(sender, e);
}
```